# Component only reachable by scrolling regardless of window size

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a layout so that the later parts of the view are only reachable by scrolling.
Currently I'm using `Dimensions` to generate Views with the correct height. Is there a better way of doing so? My current solution doesn't seem too correct.

```
export default function MyApp() {

  const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', height:height}}/>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height:40}}/>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is fine! You can also use marginBottom if you don't want to extend your component, but again your solution is a better one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use VirtualizedList component, for example as

```
<VirtualizedList
data={['body']}
renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
        {/* Put more content for body */}
    </View>

)}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
getItemCount={() => {
    return 1;
}}
getItem={(data, index) => {
    return data[index];
}}>

</VirtualizedList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution work, but not good and it have downside, when you change your phone orientation to landscape there will be bug. I dont like using `Dimensions` in my code unless there is no other way or use Dimensions `addEventListener` to listen window size and update component whenever window size change. I will suggest you a better way.

First, create a component called `LayoutSizeAwareView`, after this view rendered, we will catch it size from `onLayout` props and use them to render it children.

```js
const LayoutSizeAwareView = (props) => {
   const [size, setSize] = React.useState({width: 0, height: 0});
   return (
      <View
         ...props,
         onLayout={(e) => {
             setSize({
                  width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
                  height: e.nativeEvent.layout.height,
             })
             props.onLayout(e)
         }}
      >
          {props.children(size)}
      </View>
   )
}
```

And then, in your case, use it like this

```js
export default function MyApp() {

  return (
    <LayoutSizeAwareView style={styles.container}>
       {({width, height}) => {
            return (
               <ScrollView>
                   <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', height: height}}/>
                   <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: 40}}/>
               </ScrollView>
            )
       }}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

This way your code look even cooler, there will be some typo in my code since I dont have IDE here, but you might get the idea.